# Been getting this for 24 hours: Error talking to the Parse servers; please try again

Tags: parse-platform

I've been attempting to try out Parse.com. I started yesterday following the docs, and I've been getting this ever since:

```
mylaptop:~/Desktop  
→ curl -s https://www.parse.com/downloads/cloud_code/installer.sh | sudo /bin/bash
Password:
Fetching latest version ...
######################################################################## 100.0%
Installing ...

mylaptop:~/Desktop  
→ parse new RemoteData
Error talking to the Parse servers; please try again.
```

I was getting it last night, and thought I'd give it some time to resolve itself, but no luck.

Also surprised this is the closest I can get to the Parse people for help. Makes me hesitant to proceed, but hoping for the best.

Any ideas?

I'm on OSX...

Comment: Try looking at [these](https://www.parse.com/questions/parse-deploy-fails-python-error) [parse](https://www.parse.com/questions/error-talking-to-the-parse-servers-on-parse-deploy) [questions](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#safe=active&q=parse+error+talking+to+the+parse+servers+try+again)

Comment: @lightice11 I've done a lot of Googling before and after posting this. No dice. Those first two links are about completely different errors. The third link (google search) didn't bring up any results that helped this issue.

Comment: Ok, too bad those links didn't help you and sorry for being a bit arrogant. I don't have any more suggestions, but I recommend you ask the question on the [parse developer group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/parse-developers) as the devs seem much more active there.